# How to use if statments on Tags in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner using Beautiful Soup and I have a question to do with 'if' statements.

I am trying to scrap data from tables from a webpage but there are pro-ceding and post-ceding tables too.

All the required tables have divisions with the form , while the useless tables have various divisions.

What I thought of doing was going using find_all to search for all table divisions and then looping through the result and appending to a list all of the divisions who's .contents method had it's first item being a tag having the attribute align = 'center', but I didn't know how to do it with the tag being a Beautiful Soup object and not knowing how to work with it.

I have my attempted code below and if anyone could give me some tips it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://afltables.com/afl/stats/2018.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('tr')

lists =[]
for result in results:
    if result.contents[0] == 'align = centre':
        #append to some list
```

Comment: Did you mean `results = soup.select('td[align=center]')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you what you are looking for I believe.

```
for result in results:
    if 'align="center"' in str(result.contents[0]):
        #append to some list
```